# How to make node_modules global instead of the folder residing inside your project

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, windows-10, node-modules

I am working on lots of nodejs application and I save all my project on Google Drive (for a personal reasons, not efficiency) but I don't like that my drive is filled with thousands of similar modules that live inside `node_modules` folder.

I was hoping if there is a way to have modules reside outside the project's file.

I am using Windows 10, and I installed nodejs for windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just install your modules globally, e.g., "npm install module-name --global". Keep in mind you'll have to synchronize dependencies in different machines.